# How to add list values to the Separate strings?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, query

I am searching for the existing contact names on VF page to find duplicates.

I want to search all the words for example if it has Test,abc I want to return the results which has **Test** as well as **abc** in contact names.

I am able to do this with only the first value (list[0]). How can I search with all the values present in that list using for loop.

Part of the Controller :

```
public class dupcontactController {


    public String name{get;set;}
    public List<Contact> conlist;
    public Contact con= new Contact();

    public dupcontactController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
    }

    public pagereference search()
    {
        String namesSplit = con.Name;
        List<String> namesSplitList = new List<String>();
        namesSplitList = namesSplit.split('\\W+');

        String stringval1 = '%'+namesSplitList[0]+'%';
        conlist=Database.query('select Name,id from Contact where Name LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(stringval1)+'%\''); // here I am fetching only first word contacts. I want to fetch all matching with all the words 

        if(conlist.size()==0)
        {
            Pagereference newcontact = new Pagereference('Taking to new contact creation');
            return newcontact ;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Page:

```
 <apex:form >
             Please Enter Contact Name
                             <apex:inputField value="{!con.Name}"/>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="Search for contact match" status="status"/>


                 </apex:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- Don't use dynamic soql here.

  - Dynamic queries should only be used as a *last resort*.
- Escape those quotes!

  - (if you stick with dynamic query)
  - See also: [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm)
- You can use a `List` in your `LIKE` clause.

Working example:

```
List<String> fuzzyTerms = new List<String>();
for (String term : con.Name.split('\\W+'))
    fuzzyTerms.add('%' + term + '%');
List<Contact> results = [
    SELECT Name FROM Contact
    WHERE Name LIKE :fuzzyTerms
];
```